# Writing a list of strings into a csv

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I am a beginner Python programmer and I have been unsuccessful in looking for a solution to my issue in this forum. It may be because I am unable to describe my problem in the right jargon - I apologize in advance if this is the case.

I used BeautifulSoup to extract a list of strings from an html document. I want to transfer this list of strings into a csv (1 string per row in a single column). However, my program is placing each character of each string in its own column

```
import csv

h3List= []

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'),'html.parser')

h3 = soup.find_all('h3')

for text in h3:
    h3List.append(text.text)

with open('h3List.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in h3List: 
        print(item)
        writer.writerow(item)
```

[output csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGyR8.png)

As you can see in the image above, the output csv file places each character in each string in individual columns. I want the 'test' strings in 1 column only.

I tried this solution:

```
for item in h3List:
    print(item)
    writer.writerow([item])
```

But when my string contains spaces, for example, the string 'test hello' - the output csv separates the words in individual columns as seen below:

[image: strings with spaces]

What is wrong with my code? For the life of me, I can't seem to figure it out.

If the solution already exists in this forum, I would appreciate a link to the post. Thank you!!

Comment: I can't reproduce your second issue - `writerow(['test hello'])` doesn't treat input as 2 columns. Did you try to look into csv file using a simple text editor rather than a spreadsheet editor? Do you actually see a `"test,hello"` on every line?

Comment: that's so weird, Alexander! You are right, when I open it on a text editor, there are no commas between the words... LibreOffice is messing with me. Thank you so much for your input, hopefully I can move forward with this!

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider accepting my answer below (accepting an answer is an action separate from upvoting). I imagine the bug you got first with each character considered an element of the sequence is something that every python programmer encountered many times. This is the price people pay to make it easier to iterate through the characters of a string when this is indeed intended behavior.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for the information! I have accepted your answer as seen below, and sorry for not doing it sooner. Still getting the hang of all this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `writer.writerow` is expecting you to pass something which can be iterated - a list, a tuple or anything else. When you pass it a string it is considered an iterable - a sequence of characters. So to fix this you need to put square brackets around item at the call: make it `writer.writerow([item])` instead of `writer.writerow(item)`.

Comment: Hello Alexander!! Thanks so much for your answer, and that did work for my test.html file. However, what if my strings have spaces in between?

For example: the string 'test hello' gets placed in 2 separate columns; the string 'test hello test' is placed in 3 separate columns.

What can I do to keep these strings separated by spaces in 1 column only?

Comment: From what you describe it doesn't sound like you call `writer.writerow()` on a list with one string `'test hello'` - most likely your `writerow` argument actually contains two items (maybe some bug in construction of that list).

Answer (score 1):

Replace your current code with the following.

I am using pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

h3List= []

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('test.html'),'html.parser')

h3 = soup.find_all('h3')

for text in h3:
    h3List.append(text.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(h3List)
df.to_csv('h3_test.csv')
```

Comment: Hello everyone, I am so sorry for being an idiot. The problem was not with the code but the program I was using to check the csv file.

Apparently, LibreOffice has a default setting that uses empty space as a delimiter. Sorry for wasting your time.